# Failed to write loggind data in file using Serilog .Net Logging

Tags: c#, logging

I am new Serail log, I have created this configuration for log file

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File(Application.dataPath + "/AppLogs.txt",rollingInterval:RollingInterval.Day).CreateLogger();
```

And using this to log details (I hope that it should also be written in log file mentioned above)

```
Log.Information("Test Log info ");
Log.Error("Test Log Error");
```

But the file created successfully with no log. Which thing i am missing. I want to log data in the file using serail log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use static functions

```
Log.Information("Test Log info ");
Log.Error("Test Log Error");
```

I have to set global statically accessible logger after the configuration

```
Log.Logger = log;
```

So my final Config code is

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File(Application.dataPath + "/AppLogs.txt",rollingInterval:RollingInterval.Day).CreateLogger();
Log.Logger = log ;//setting global logger
```